# ASP.NET: Editing Item from ListView using an ImageButton

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, imagebutton

I'm having some problems with the ListView control of ASP.NET. I'm trying to add editing options to each item and it works if I use a LinkButton with CommandName="Edit", but (and here is the problem) I need to use an ImageButton instead of the LinkButton and it doesn't work, although I've read that it's not a problem (http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/061009-1.aspx). I also have tried to nest the ImageButton inside the LinkButton, but it doesn't work.

This is my markup code for the ImageButton:

`<asp:ImageButton ID="editCircleIcon" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Edit this circle" AlternateText="edit" Width="20px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Circulos/edit_circle.png" style="float:right;" />`

I also have tried to put a break point inside the ItemEditing event of the ListView but it's never accessed.

Any idea?

Thanks!!!

PD: This is the entire ListView:

```
<asp:ListView id="listOfCircles" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" ItemPlaceholderID="circlePlaceHolder">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:label ID="noCircles" runat="server" Text="No circles defined" />
    </EmptyDataTemplate>

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="circle" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" Width="100%">
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="circlePlaceHolder" />
        </asp:Panel>    
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="circleID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
        <asp:Panel ID="circleHeader" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px">
            <asp:Image ID="circleIcon" runat="server" />
            <asp:Label ID="circleName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nombre") %>'  />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="deleteCircleIcon" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Circulos/delete_circle.png" width="20px" style="float:right;" ToolTip="Delete this circle" CommandName="Delete" />
                <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender id="deleteCircleCBE" runat="server"
                                                   DisplayModalPopupID="deleteCircleMPE"
                                                   TargetControlID="deleteCircleIcon" />
                <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="deleteCircleMPE" runat="server"
                                                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
                                                PopupControlID="deleteCirclePopup" TargetControlID="deleteCircleIcon"
                                                OkControlID="deleteCircleOk" CancelControlID="deleteCircleCancel"
                                                DropShadow="true" />
                <asp:Panel ID="deleteCirclePopup" runat="server" CssClass="PopUp" style="display:none">
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="deleteCircleClosePopup" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/closePopupIcon.png" CssClass="closePopupImage" OnClientClick="$find('deleteCirclePopup').hide();" />
                    <br /><br /><br />
                    <asp:Label id="deleteCircleMssg" runat="server" Text="Are you sure do you want to delete this circle?" />
                    <br /><br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteCircleOk" runat="server" Text="delete" />&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteCircleCancel" runat="server" Text="cancel" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="editCircleIcon" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Edit this circle" AlternateText="edit" Width="20px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Circulos/edit_circle.png" style="float:right;" OnCommand="editCircleIcon_OnClick" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="editCircleLinkButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Edit this circle" style="float:right;" Text="Edit" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="circleMiddle" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px">
            <asp:Panel ID="users" runat="server">
            <%--espacio para que salgan los usuarios del circulo--%>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="circleFooter" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px">
                <a href="#" onclick='showPopup(newUserPanelPopup, <%# Eval("id") %>)'><img src="/Images/Circulos/add_friend.png" width="20px" alt="Add user" style="margin: 0" title="Add a new user to this circle" /></a>
        </asp:Panel>
        <br /><br />
    </ItemTemplate>

    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="circleHeaderEditMode" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" DefaultButton="editCircleOk" style="background-color:#DDD;">
            <asp:Image ID="circleIcon" runat="server" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="circleNewName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nombre") %>' />
            <asp:Button ID="editCircleCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" style="float:right" CommandName="Cancel" />
            <asp:Button ID="editCircleOk" runat="server" Text="Update" style="float:right" CommandName="Update" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <br /><br />
    </EditItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

Right now, I've two controls for the edit option, the ImageButton that doesn't work and the LinkButton.

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you post the whole ListView?

Comment: Does OnCommand="editCircleIcon_OnClick" exist? Does it do a postback or anything when you click the ImageButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've solved the issue. I was refilling the ListView on each PostBack. The solution is easy:

```
If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        ReFillList()
    End If
```

Mysteriously, LinkButton doesn't seem bothered by that and the the Delete option always works... If anyone knows the reason, I would love to know why.

Thanks everybody!!

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this.

```
OnCommand="ImageButton_Command"
```

This shows how to hook it up.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.commandname.aspx#Y0

Comment: Really, I'm not looking for an alternative method but for an explanation to this problem that have not sense to me.

For example, I've an ImageButton with CommandName="Delete" which works without problem, but if I set CommandName="Edit" it doesnt work.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Then please post the rest of the list view

Comment: Mmmmm I'm trying to put the code answering myself but stackoverflow is telling me that I've to wait 8 hours for that :_(

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on my computer, and I found that if your code behind method is something like this

```
Private Sub editCircleIcon_Command(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs) Handles editCircleIcon.Command
    If e.CommandName = "Edit" Then
       ... //your code
    End If
End Sub
```

and you use your imagebutton

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="editCircleIcon" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Edit this circle" AlternateText="edit" Width="20px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Circulos/edit_circle.png" style="float:right;" />
```

the codebehind was executed. If you would post what the code behind looks like I might be more helpful.

I hope this helps.